# SQL While Loop in 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Anyone have a sample of how to do a WHILE Loop in 2005 SQL without using a cursor? I'd like to loop through based on a counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 10

WHILE @i > 0
BEGIN 

   SELECT @i -- Output: 10, 9, 8, etc...

   SET @i = @i - 1
END
```

But you should first examine more carefully if what you are trying to do can be achieved using *set based* operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=10000)
BEGIN

PRINT @intFlag


-- DO YOUR WORK HERE


SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1

END
GO
```